# invalidSharingRequest error when insert permission using Google Drive API v2

Tags: java, permissions, google-drive-api

POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId/permissions
Result :

```
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidSharingRequest",
    "message": "Bad Request. User message: \"이 항목의 소유자를 아직 변경할 수 없습니다. Google에서 이 문제에 대한 해결 방안을 연구하는 중입니다.\""
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request. User message: \"이 항목의 소유자를 아직 변경할 수 없습니다. Google에서 이 문제에 대한 해결 방안을 연구하는 중입니다.\""
 }

//message : You can not change the owner of this item yet. Is being studied for a possible solution to this problem on Google.
```

I'm using App Engine SDK 1.9.0.

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: You need to post more code the problem cant be recreated with the code you have here.

Comment: There is a problem with all files of only a particular user under the code.
Do you know any situation when this “InvalidSharingRequest” error occurs?